# CSS отступ от текста

Tags: html, css

Есть галерея картинок, хочу сделать так, чтобы отступ был везде одинаковый. А то получается вот как: есть товар, где текст либо очень маленький, и полоска лезет на галерею (закрывая ее), или очень много, что отступ гигантский получается.

Вот так получается когда текста мало или нет вообще:

[image: img1]

А так когда текста много:

[image: img2]

Нужно чтобы везде было одинаково.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень похоже на то, что вы используете для картинки `float: left`, но перед галереей картинок его не обнуляете, поэтому и верхний отступ для галереи так плохо срабатывает.

Comment: @Genson можете подсказать как его обнулить? Создать <div id="clear"></div>?

Comment: Я бы вам так не советовал, лучше для галереи картинок задать css-свойство clear:both , но оно может порушить вашу структуру. Можете скинуть ссылку на рабочий вариант?

Comment: @Genson к сожалению рабочего варианта пока нет :( 
А почему-бы не советовали?

Comment: Зачем вам лишний элемент в разметке? Тогда уже используйте ".clearfix".